# pandas long to wide windowing

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to reshape a data frame by converting 'windows' of row data to column data. For instance, with a window size of 2, given the data frame:

```
    A   B
 0  a1  b1
 1  a2  b2
 2  a3  b3
 3  a4  b4
```

I would like to produce the data frame:

```
    A1 A2 B1 B2
 0  a1 a2 b1 b2
 1  a2 a3 b2 b3
 2  a3 a4 b3 b4
```

This is tricky, because a cell in the old data frame may not have a unique index in the produced data frame.

I could of course do something complicated like iterating over rows in the old data frame, computing the location of a cell in the new, and simply copying the data. But I would like a simpler solution...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can view the operation with window size of 2 as shifting the DataFrame upward by one row, concatenating it horizontally with the original DataFrame, and finally some reordering. Thus, without iterating over rows it can be done like this:

```
res = df.merge(df.shift(-1), left_index=True, right_index=True).iloc[:-1]
res.columns = ['A1', 'B1', 'A2', 'B2']
res = res[['A1', 'A2', 'B1', 'B2']]
print res
```

Output:

```
   A1  A2  B1  B2
0  a1  a2  b1  b2
1  a2  a3  b2  b3
2  a3  a4  b3  b4
```

This can be generalized to to arbitrary DataFrame and windows size:

```
def rolling(df, window_size=2):
    dfs = [df]
    for i in range(1, window_size):
        dfs.append(df.shift(-i))
    res = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1).iloc[:-(window_size-1)]
    colnames = [c + str(i) for i in range(1, window_size+1) for c in df.columns]
    reorder = [c + str(i) for c in df.columns for i in range(1, window_size+1)]
    res.columns = colnames
    return res[reorder]

print rolling(df, 3)
```

Output:

```
   A1  A2  A3  B1  B2  B3
0  a1  a2  a3  b1  b2  b3
1  a2  a3  a4  b2  b3  b4
```

Comment: Very nice! Upon further reflection, my problem actually required the window function to be applied to each row in the original data frame, leaving NaN where the are no values below. This can be achieved simply by removing the .iloc call on the result of the concatenation.